# Get the number of changed value when I use UPDATE from mysql.connector

Tags: mysql-python

I want to get the number of changed value when I use UPDATE with mysql.connector.

My SQL itself is working, but I want to know how many are changed when it runs.

My code is like this.

I want to monitor how many are changed through this SQL.

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = MY_HOST,
    port = 3306,
    user = my_account,
    password = my_password,
    database = dbname,
)

dbh = myconn(my_database)
cur = dbh.cursor()

sql = 'UPDATE my_table' SET any_column=0 WHERE condition=1'

result1 = cur.execute(sql) # result is None
result2 = dbh.commit()     # result is None
```

I expect the number changed, not None value like now.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried accessing `cur.rowcount`?

the code should be like this

```
dbh = myconn(my_database)
cur = dbh.cursor()

sql = 'UPDATE my_table' SET any_column=0 WHERE condition=1'

cur.execute(sql) 
dbh.commit()     

result = cur.rowcount
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the result was not as expected. But I tried to use another complicated codes to fix this problem.